# jQueryMobile - How do I change a listview's data-inset value via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

I am developing our mobile application in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. Each of our main pages will have a listview for displaying various types of data.  If the app is running on a tablet, or in a landscape view where the screen is larger than certain width, I'd like the listviews to have the data-inset property set to true, and be rendered with rounded corners and borders.  If it's on a smaller screen that is under the predefined width, I'd like it to not have the inset property.

In my function, I do something like this to set the data-inset property:

```
var list = $("#testlist");
list.data("inset", true);
list.listview("refresh",true);
```

However, this doesn't update the list.  It stays formatted to fit the full width of the screen.   How should I accomplish this goal?  I thought about manually adding the styles, but I'd have to not only add it to the list, but each list item.  Is there a way I can just toggle the data-inset property and trigger the framework to restyle it?

Here's a semi-working jsFiddle that mimics what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/GQgV9/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no civilized way to do that. Refreshing will only update widget's internals. In order to make the list inset, you have to:

1. Set inset classes on the `<ul>`, .i.e. `ui-listview-inset` and `ui-corner-all`.
2. Set `inset` option via `.listview('option', 'inset', true)`.
3. Refresh widget because otherwise list items won't have round corners.

Here is the modified version of your jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GQgV9/13/

Comment: Bingo.  That did it.  Thanks for the prompt response!  I had also tried setting the classes, but not the two at the same time.  This works for what I need.

Comment: There is a problem with li's with anchors when resetting the data-inset to false after it was set to true. I reset the classes and inset value but some of the styling stays (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/GQgV9/18/).

From the doc, any markup that doesn't change is ignored by the listview refresh.  My guess is when we switch it back it ignores refreshing some of the anchor styles since they didn't change. A probable fix for this is rebuilding the list, but that could be expensive. Looking into a solution to this. I hope it's as simple as removing an extra style from the li's containing anchors.

Comment: Should have spent more time on it before commenting :)  Removing the "true" attribute from the .listview('refresh',true) fixed it.  So just use .listview('refresh').